# Inconsistent accessibility error with public field

Tags: c#

I've already looked in the forum for my problem, saying something about it being private, but I've put all my methods and class into public but I still get this error:

> Error1 Inconsistent accessibility: field type '`A_Day_at_the_races.Bet`' is less accessible than field '`A_Day_at_the_races.Guy.MyBet`'

This is my code:

```
public class Guy
{
    public string Name; // The Guy's name
    public Bet MyBet; // An instance of Bet() that has his bet
    public int Cash; //How much cash he has
    // GUI controls on the form
    public RadioButton MyRadioButton; // My RadioButton
    public Label MyLabel; // My Label
}
```

Comment: Show us the Bet class definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `Bet` type was declared as internal. Either you explicitly declared it as internal, or if you didn't provide any accessibility modifier, it will be considered internal by default.

Try making your `Bet` type public instead:

```
public class Bet { ... } // or public struct Bet / public interface Bet
```

You can then use it to declare public members of other public types:

```
public class Guy
{
    public Bet MyBet; // or public Bet MyBet { get; set; } to create a property
    ...
}
```

**Further Reading**

- [Accessibility Levels (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, but I can't turn it into a class because I will get lots of errors

Comment: @user3043427 Is it an interface? A struct? It doesn't matter, just make it public.

Comment: Invalid token '}' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
if I change it to: "public class Bet {MyBet};".

Comment: Btw how do I read dcastro's comment, I can only see part of it.
Sorry I'am new on this forum.

Comment: @user3043427 Then you've done something wrong. Please show how you've declared `Bet`.

Comment: @user3043427 If you mean you can only read part of it in your global inbox (the little area at the top of the page), then just click on the comment there and it will take you to the full comment.

Comment: @user3043427 You're trying to change the definition of `MyBet`. Don't do that, that's not what this answer says, this answer says to change the definition of `Bet`.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhh, got it guys! I didn't have the class Bet as public

Comment: Damn I can't give you guys reputatie because I'am to low myself.